# change combobox selecteditem in datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

hi how i can change my combobox in datatemplate? why i cant use my combobox name like this:

```
cmbBase.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

this is my Datatemplate

```
<ContentControl>
                                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <ComboBox Name="cmbBase">
                                                <ComboBoxItem Content="اول"/>
                                                <ComboBoxItem Content="دوم"/>
                                                <ComboBoxItem Content="سوم"/>
                                                <ComboBoxItem Content="چهارم"/>
                                                <ComboBoxItem Content="پنجم"/>
                                                <ComboBoxItem Content="ششم"/>
                                            </ComboBox>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text=" انتخاب پایه " IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger SourceName="cmbBase" Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                            </ContentControl>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do ? i dont see that you are trying to change your combobox box in the data template you provided , but i see you are using the combobox name (and you are using it correctly) but you are asking why you cant use combobox name(your example will work with the combobox box name) .

Comment: because cmBase name not accesible in code behind

Comment: You should look into mvvm.  Bind your control and template properties to properties in a viewmodel and then you change the data in the viewmodel rather than trying to find controls by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy suggested you need to look into MVVM. if you still want to get it from the code behind please see how to use
[FrameworkTemplate.FindName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname(v=vs.100).aspx)

PS, if you are trying to place text above the combobox until user selects an item this is not the way to do it, try looking into how to do combobox with watermark you will find plenty of answers in this site .